# Парсинг контента с разными ID

Tags: simple-html-dom, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи, совсем недавно я заинтересовался парсингом страниц, обычно для парсинга использую библиотеку Simple html DOM.

Но вот у меня стала задача спарсить контент со страницы одного сайта, но вот проблема появилась, дело в том, что у этого сайта каждый блок новости имеет HTML тег с разными ID'ами.

Пример:

```
<div id="post-209">
<div id="post-2010">
```

Хочу также учесть то, что текст новости можно считать только через эти теги, остальные выводят лишнюю информацию.

Возможно ли как нибудь это обойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не работал напрямую с simple html dom, но он наверняка понимает обычные css-селекторы

```
div[id^="post-"]
```

Это не регулярка, это валидный css-селектор. Просто используется схожий синтаксис для простоты запоминания.

Comment: Не до конца уверен что Simple html работает с регулярками, но попробую. Хотя должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо, все ок работает ;)